# JSON integers returning as 0 when they should be values

Tags: json, go

I have the following JSON file and am trying to Parse it out.

```
{
"coord":
{
"lon":-121.31,
"lat":38.7},
"weather":[
{
"id":800,
"main":"Clear",
"description":"clear sky",
"icon":"01d"}
],
"base":"stations",
"main":
{
"temp":73.26,
"pressure":1018,
"humidity":17,
"temp_min":68,
"temp_max":77},
```

The expected output is:
Current Temperature:73
Today's Low:68
Today's High:77
Current Humidity:17%

but it is instead returning:
Current Temperature:0
Today's Low:0
Today's High:0
Current Humidity:0%

This is the code I am trying to use to get the desired return:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)


type Daily struct {
    Currenttemp int `json:"temp"`
    Mintemp     int `json:"temp_min"`
    Maxtemp     int `json:"temp_max"`
    Humidity    int `json:"humidity"`
}


func main() {
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("jsontest1.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened jsontest1.json")

    defer jsonFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    var daily Daily

    json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &daily)


    fmt.Println("Current Temperature:"+strconv.Itoa(daily.Currenttemp))
    fmt.Println("Today's Low:"+strconv.Itoa(daily.Mintemp))
    fmt.Println("Today's High:"+strconv.Itoa(daily.Maxtemp))
    fmt.Println("Current Humidity:"+strconv.Itoa(daily.Humidity)+"%")


}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Check Unmarshal's return value.

Comment: 0 0 0 0 was the value when printing daily

Comment: Your struct does only remotely resemble the input, namely a part of it. You need to unmarshal the *whole* input into a fitting struct, and then select from it what you actually need. Oh, and btw, [Unmarshal returns an error](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal), which prolly will tell you that your json is invalid in the first place. **NEVER skip evaluation of errors.**

Comment: I have changed the types to properly reflect those in the json, and using struct{Main Daily} I can return the proper values, but I still can't reference the original struct to put the values into a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your sample JSON input is badly formatted: it ends with `},` when it should end with `}}`.  This causes `json.Unmarshal` to return an error:

```
unexpected EOF
```

Fixing that leads to lots more problems, many of which people have noted in comments.  For instance, your input does not have the same structure as your `struct`, and JSON numbers decode to `float64`, not `int`.  One of the values—the one with the key `"temp"`—is `73.26`, which is not an integer.

I have a mild dislike of quietly ignoring unknown fields, so I like to use a `json.Decoder` in which unknown fields are disallowed.  This helps make sure you didn't screw up the data structure by using the wrong tag or a tag at the wrong level, because when you *do*, you just get all the missing fields as zero.  So I like to add an "ignored" decoder for explicitly ignoring fields:

```
type ignored [0]byte
func (i *ignored) UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error {
    return nil
}
```

You can then declare fields of type `ignored` and yet still give them json tags (though the default of matching the name of the field tends to suffice):

```
type overall struct {
    Coord   ignored
    Weather ignored
    Base    ignored
    Main    Daily
}
```

If you really want to unmarshal directly to an integer type, you need to get fancy again, which I did in my example.  It's probably wiser just to unmarshal straight to `float64` though.  If you do that—use `float64` and don't add a special type just to ignore certain fields—you can drop the use of `json.NewDecoder`.

You can get even fancier and use pointers to be able to tell if your fields were filled in or not, but I did not do this in my example.  I snipped out the file reading (and the lack of error checking on the read call) and used hardcoded input data instead.  The final version, in which decoding does work, is [here on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L_jU1bulNaA).